# Prevent "invalid byte sequence" errors while using psql within iTerm on Mac OS X Catalina

Tags: mac, keyboard, terminal, unicode

I've been working on a MacBook Pro for a few months now, and it's been going fine except for one thing that's driving me nuts: sometimes when I type commands into psql, I get 'invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"' errors. The problem looks something like this:

```
user=> SELECT mycol FROM table WHERE mycol2 IS NULL;
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xc3 0x4c
user=> SELECT mycol FROM table WHERE mycol2 IS NULL;
 ?column?
----------
...(expected output here)
```

(Pressing the up arrow to repeat the command exactly doesn't work; I have to retype it.)

Experimenting within the shell, it seems like specifically, this is probably happening when I accidentally type a non-ASCII character and then erase it - for example, on my Icelandic keyboard it's easy to accidentally type ´ when I'm going for *, or þ when I'm going for a period. It seems the 0xc3 byte gets inserted when I type it in, but isn't erased properly when I erase the typo, even though it *looks* fine.

It does seem if I erase a couple more times I can delete the errant byte and "untaint" the line, but this is incredibly annoying - most of the time I just automatically correct typos as I go without consciously thinking about it, and if I let even one pass by without extra backspace presses, the whole thing breaks.

Is there any way to make the shell behave as expected, i.e. properly erase the entire character when I press backspace once?

I'm running psql while ssh'ed into a Vagrant VM within iTerm, if any of that changes anything.

Comment: Have you tried changing iTerm's default encoding to something other than UTF8?

Comment: @Spiff Well, that does fix the erasing of typos! It feels quite hackish, though; as indicated by the error messages, the database *is* UTF-8 and the database shell should be expecting UTF-8 input. When iTerm is set to UTF-8 I can do queries with non-ASCII characters just fine - the problem is only when I try to erase those characters. While I don't do a lot of database queries involving non-ASCII characters, changing the terminal encoding obviously just breaks that completely and I'm not super keen on that. Is there a better way?